# What chemicals react with alcohol?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am curious if there is any chemicals that react with alcohol to either produce a visible colour change or an odour someone could smell.

Comment: As it stands this question is rather broad. What application are you looking for here? For example, potassium dichromate will react with alcohol to produce a colour change, but it will also react with other things to produce the same colour change.

Comment: For contamination purposes I wanted to be able to see if there is alcohol in a substance by either sight or odour.

Comment: How can I tell if a liquid contains alcohol with the addition of a chemicals with the cheapest and least toxic option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "alcohol", I am not sure if you are referring to ethanol (drinking alcohol) or alcohols in general so in my example I will use ethanol. When an alcohol is combined with a carbocylic acid and a catalyst, they will produce esters (fragrances). For example, ethanol and ethanoic acid would react to produce ethyl ethanoate (a fruity smelling substance) and water.

[image]

There are a plethora of different reactions from all different types of alcohols and carbocylic acids that produce countless different smells. The fragrances also come in a variety of colors as well. If you want to find out more, I would suggest looking up ester synthesis. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: carboxylic acid not carbocyclic acid.